# Welford online algorithm for updating the sample variance.

Tags: probability, algorithms, variance

I was looking at the [Welford online algorithm to update the variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford%27s_online_algorithm). If we denote by $M_n = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline{x}_n)^2$ where $\overline{x}_n = (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)/n$ is the sample mean, I want to verify that $M_n = M_{n-1}+(x_n-\overline{x}_{n-1})(x_n-\overline{x}_n)$ which is the claim on wikipedia.
But I get
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(x_i-\overline{x}_{n-1})^2+(x_n-\overline{x}_{n-1})(x_n-\overline{x}_n)\\
=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline{x}_{n-1})^2-(x_n-\overline{x}_{n-1})^2+(x_n-\overline{x}_{n-1})(x_n-\overline{x}_n)\\
= \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline{x}_{n-1})^2-(x_n-\overline{x}_{n-1})(\overline{x}_{n-1}-\overline{x}_n)\\
= \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline{x}_{n-1})^2-n(\overline{x}_n-\overline{x}_{n-1})^2
\end{align}

where the last step is because
\begin{align}
\overline{x}_n-\overline{x}_{n-1} = \frac{(n-1)\overline{x}_{n-1}+x_n}{n}- \frac{n\overline{x}_{n-1}}{n}=\frac{x_n-\overline{x}_{n-1}}{n}
\end{align}

Then

\begin{align}
M_{n-1}+(x_n-\overline{x}_{n-1})(x_n-\overline{x}_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n[(x_i-\overline{x}_{n-1})^2-(\overline{x}-\overline{x}_{n-1})^2]\\
=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline{x}_{n-1}+\overline{x}_n-\overline{x}_{n-1})(x_i-\overline{x}_{n-1}-\overline{x}_n+\overline{x}_{n-1})\\
=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline{x}_{n-1}+\overline{x}_n-\overline{x}_{n-1})(x_i-\overline{x}_n)
\end{align}

which is not the right conclusion.

Comment: You are almost done. All you have to do now is to prove the easy identity $\,0 = \sum_{i=1}^n (2\overline{x}_{n-1}-2\overline{x}_n)(x_i-\overline{x}_n).$

Comment: Thank you @Somos, this is true since $\sum_{i=1}^n(\overline{x}_n-x_i) = n\overline{x}_n-n\overline{x}_n=0$